# Why is this symbolic link created two instances

Tags: bash, zsh

I have an install script used for my dotfiles. I am using to create symbolic links of one directory to my home folder. The links execute fine apart but a second symobolic link is created and I cannot reason why.

The folder structure in the project looks like this

```
install.sh
scripts/
    shell.sh
shell/
```

`install.sh` calls `shell.sh` and that calls the command

```
ln -s $SCRIPTS_DIR/shell/ $HOME/.shell
```

$SCRIPTS_DIR is a full path

So I do get a .shell directory in my home directory linked just fine but now my project folder has an extra symbolic link

```
install.sh
scripts/
    shell -> PATH_TO_PROJECT/shell
    shell.sh 
shell/
```

Any explanation would be appreciated

Comment: Not a zsh problem -- `ln -s` will behave this way with any shell, if not given the GNU extensions `-h` or `-n`.

Comment: By the way -- for user-defined variables such as `SCRIPTS_DIR`, all-caps variable names aren't good form; within environment variables (with which shell variables share a namespace), all-caps names are reserved for builtin variables and names of environment variables that modify the system's operation. See the fourth paragraph of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html

Comment: BTW, that the code you gave is correct only for zsh and not for bash (where it needs more quotes) perhaps makes a point about how tagging for both shells is bad form.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for the link, I've moved all my app variables to lower case. What did you mean by needs more quotes? it seems to be working fine on my bash and zsh shells

Comment: Try making `scripts_dir` point to a directory with spaces in its name, and you'll see it fail in bash (or any POSIX-compliant shell; this works in zsh only because zsh breaks the standard).

Comment: ...incidentally, that's why I stopped using zsh more than a decade ago -- I found that using it interactively got me in the habit of being sloppy, so I was writing code with bugs when targeting other shells.

Comment: Interesting, I just made the move to zsh so I might have to rethink that. thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Think about what happens when you run the `ln -s` command twice when its target is a directory rather than a file.

If `$HOME/.shell` doesn't exist, then

```
ln -s "$SCRIPTS_DIR/shell/" "$HOME/.shell"
```

...creates it. However, if it *already* exists, then...

```
ln -s "$SCRIPTS_DIR/shell/" "$HOME/.shell"
```

...treats `.shell` as a destination directory name, not a complete path to the destination to be created, and creates a new entry *within* that directory.

---

GNU `ln` has some extensions to fix this usage, including:

> -h    If the target_file or target_dir is a symbolic link, do not follow it.  This is most useful with the -f option, to replace a symlink which may point to a directory.

Thus, if operating on a GNU system, you could use:

```
# quotes added for bash compatibility, since question is tagged for both shells
ln -sfh "$SCRIPTS_DIR/shell/" "$HOME/.shell"
```

---

Otherwise, just check first:

```
[[ -e $HOME/.shell ]] || ln -s "$SCRIPTS_DIR/shell/" "$HOME/.shell"
```