# Why is 'which' finding two instances of the same symbolic link in Linux?

Tags: linux, shell

As I was setting up [rtags](https://github.com/Andersbakken/rtags), I created a symbolic link to `gcc-rtags-wrapper.sh` named `g++` using below.

```
sudo ln -s ~/rtags/bin/gcc-rtags-wrapper.sh ~/bin/g++
```

And added the directory of the newly created link to `$PATH` in the shell config file (*fish shell*).

In order to check that I was successful in doing so, I ran `which -a g++ | xargs file` in the terminal expecting to see a single instance of `g++` instead I got with two instances of the same symbolic lnik to `gcc-rtags-wrapper.sh`.

```
/home/grey/bin//g++: symbolic link to `/home/grey/rtags/bin/gcc-rtags-wrapper.sh' 
/home/grey/bin/g++:  symbolic link to `/home/grey/rtags/bin/gcc-rtags-wrapper.sh' 
/usr/bin/g++:        symbolic link to `g++-4.8'
```

I think this is  a very newb question but why is this the case? Thanks in advance.

*I did take a look at a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30470530/why-is-this-symbolic-link-created-two-instances) but thought that my case was different since I was making a link to a specific file and not a directory.*

*EDIT:*

*THANK YOU! @David C. Rankin, @Greg A. Woods & @jlliagre!!!*

My `$PATH` variable did have both `*/bin` and `*/bin/`. Running `which -a g++ | xargs file` after removing one of the includes returned a single instance of `g++`! I wrongly assumed that redundant includes in the `$PATH` variable would be ignored.

Comment: Please show the value of your `$PATH` variable.

Comment: `PATH` will be interesting, but `which` is already reporting all instances of the executable found in `PATH`.per the `-a` option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is unrelated to the fact there are symbolic links or not. Your PATH contains both `/home/grey/bin/` and `/home/grey/bin`. `which -a` doesn't stop when the first occurence of the command is found so reports the redundant one.